# selecting specific number of cells in array using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Is it possible to select specific number of of cells in an array based on the index?

for example selecting all cells starting from index 5 to index 15.

I know we can do that using loop or array.copy().

But my question is that possible using LINQ ?

If so, can you paste a demo code ?

and what about effeciency ?

Comment: about efficiency both linq approach and copy are efficient and will  run at same speed.

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary, I'm afraid that using `.Skip(n).Take(m)` is not so efficient as using `Array.Copy`. `Skip/Take` will take O(n + m) time while `Array.Copy` only O(m) time.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko yes. i didnt notice that. btw for small collections it wouldn't make performance issue.

Comment: So, arr.skip(0).take(m) is the same as Array.Copy ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with the following construction:

```
arr.Skip(5).Take(10);
```